# using csplit and using "incr|full|manual" operator but i like to know which one was match in a line

Tags: powershell, csplit

I have lines

```
bpdppa301p.corpads.local 86929680 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR JC_FS UNIX_FS01_INCR incr 02/24/2022 03/30/2022 03/30/2022  disk 1645678800 backup 84 MB /dbwsrp01/dbwsrp01           JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
bpdppa301p.corpads.local 82578060 MN_DB_ORA                manual 02/24/2022 04/21/2022 03/31/2022         disk 1645678854              80 MB RMAN:PFDPRE01_jf0mjj9l_1_1    MNBDD3302P.corpads.local
bpdppa301p.corpads.local 86929880 JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR JC_FS UNIX_FS01_INCR Notincr 02/24/2022 03/30/2022 03/30/2022  disk 1645678800 backup 84 MB /dbwsrp01/dbwsrp01           JCBDD1300P.corpads.local
```

i am picking line by below code
$mn=$line -csplit "incr|full|manual"
but i also need way to capture which one was match incr or full or manual in a line. any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `()` to capture the matched word, this will make PowerShell include it in the output from the split operation:

```
$mn = $line -csplit "(incr|full|manual)"
$mn[1] # this will now contain `incr`, `full` or `manual`
```

Comment: This is documented in [about_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split).